# how to use tailwind css for navbar and items show in loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navbar, tailwind-css

```
<div >
{categories?.data && 
categories.data.map((category) => (
<div key={category.id} onClick={ () => handleClick(category.id)} >
{category.name}
</div>
```

this is my code and needs to look category in the navbar

Comment: Please provide full example, it would be better to use the code snippet or use one of live editors like fiddle or sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Simple you switch out the  tag for a  tag, and the work with the tailwind classes on the navbar. Sample from the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#loops) below.

Furthermore you need to return the jsx you want to display. See the sample below.

```
 <nav class="flex justify-center space-x-4">
      {categories?.data && 
      categories.data.map((category) => (return(
      <div key={category.id} onClick={ () => handleClick(category.id)} >
      {category.name})
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
{
  categories?.data && categories.data.map((category) => (
    <div key={category.id} onClick={ () => handleClick(category.id)} >
       {category.name}
    </div>
}
</div>
```

This should work!